# How do you connect a git repo to gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have installed git and setup gerrit on my local PC.

In my folder *C:\git\Gerrit\git* I have created a repo.  I made come changes to the contained file, added and committed it.

I then pushed it to gerrit using the command:

> git push origin head:refs/for/master

and I get the reply:

> Enumerating objects: 5, done.   Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 273 bytes | 273.00 KiB/s, done.  Total 3 
>   (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)  To origin     71f7b5d..0375419  head ->
>   refs/for/master

Whereas in documentation I have followed the reply was supposed to be of the form

> $ git commit [master 3cc9e62]  Change to a proper, yeast based pizza
>   dough.    1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)   $ git
>   push origin HEAD:refs/for/master Counting objects: 3, done.  Delta
>   compression using up to 8 threads.   Compressing objects: 100% (2/2),
>   done.   Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 532 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
>   Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)  remote: Processing changes:
>   new: 1, done remote:  remote: New Changes:  remote:
>   http://gerrithost/#/c/RecipeBook/+/702 Change to a proper, yeast based
>   pizza dough.   remote: To ssh://gerrithost:29418/RecipeBook  * [new
>   branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master

But nothing appears in gerrit.  I am looking on the page identified as the CannonicalWebURL in the config file.

I presume I need to link the repo and gerrit together somehow but I cannot seem to work out how to do it.
Has anyone gone through this?

Comment: First: what do you mean by "I have created a repo" (have you create a repository using "git init" or have you cloned a repository using "git clone"?). Second: add the url you're using to look for the change.

Comment: I created a new one from scratch with 'git init'.  I am not sure I am not sure the URL will be accessible for you as it is on my local PC?

Comment: Inside your local repository execute: "git remote -v" and post the result. Have you executed "git push origin head:refs/for/master" or "git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master"?

Comment: git remote -v" gives: 
gerrit  MyMachineName.MyDomain.local:TestProject (fetch)
gerrit  MyMachineName.MyDomain.local:TestProject (push)

I used git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master, is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how did you get the remote "gerrit MyMachineName.MyDomain.local:TestProject" using just "git init" (is there any configuration in your .gitconfig file?) but if you want to create a new repository in Gerrit you must do the following steps:

1. Log in the Gerrit web tool
2. Create the repository in the Gerrit UI at
   BROWSE > Repositories > CREATE NEW
3. Clone the empty repository using
   the "git clone" command available in the Gerrit UI at BROWSE >
   Repositories >
4. Create whatever you want and commit
   your changes
5. Push to Gerrit executing: "git push origin
   HEAD:refs/for/master"

See more info in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html)